# Replacement for deprecated AssetsService

Tags: assets

Im developing my first plugin and was interested in using the `findFolder()` method from `AssetsService` but i noticed the class is depreciated. What is the proper way of achieiving the functionality of `findFolder()` without using the deprecated class? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the Assets related classes in Craft 2 have been deprecated because they've been completely re-written/refactored/removed for the upcoming Craft 3.

So if you're looking for a Craft 2 replacement, there isn't one... the replacements are in Craft 3.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I'll use the deprecated class for now until craft 3 is officially released :)